# Error fatal : No capturado ArgumentCountError: mysqli_select_db () espera exactamente 2 argumentos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de hacer una conexión con un formulario, a la hora de ejecutarlo me dice que hay problemas con la base de datos.La base de datos ya la cree en phpmyadmin. ¿Me podrían ayudar por favor?

El codigo es :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  
<title>Insertar base de datos</title>  
</head>  
<body>  

 <?php 
 $conexion = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","alumnos01") or die 
 ("Problemas en la conexión");
 mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "SELECT * FROM alumnos01") or die 
 ("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos");


 mysqli_query ("INSERT INTO alumnos (nombre, direccion, telefono)
 VALUES ('$nombre','$direccion','$telefono')") or die (mysqli_error());


 echo "El alumno fue dado de alta";

 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Y el error que me dice es "**Problemas en la selección de la base de datos**"

Comment: Has verificado que esté todo correcto en esta línea __mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","alumnos01")__, me refiero a los parámetros recibidos.

Comment: @BetaM si solo pongo como argumento el nombre de la base de datos, me aparece el siguiente error : **
Error fatal : No capturado ArgumentCountError: mysqli_select_db () espera exactamente 2 argumentos

Comment: @DamianGarcia si , estan correctos

Comment: @Emily es por que los valores que pasas no son los indicados, te recomiendo leas la documentación ahi se expone la solución: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: Después de esto "$conexion = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","alumnos01")"; 
Pon esta linea: 
**if(!$conexion ) {
     die('No se pudo conectar a la BD: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}**
saca el "or die" también. De esta manera tendras un mejor detalle del error.

Answer (score 2):

El problema se puede dividir en 2 puntos iniciales:

1. Si ya estás usando el método `mysqli_connect` esta demás que indiques la base de datos seleccionada a través del método `mysql_select_db`, (*ya indicas cual es en el cuarto argumento*)
2. Por otro lado el error que mencionas en los comentarios se debe a que al usar `mysqli_select_db` en un [estilo orientado por procedimientos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php#refsect1-mysqli.select-db-description) debes considerar 2 argumentos:

   - conexion
   - nombre de la base de datos

Entonces esto:

```
mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "SELECT * FROM alumnos01")
```

Debe pasar a esto:

```
mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "alumnos01")
```

Anotaciones:

- Sin embargo como ya mencioné, esto último esta demás pues tu novena línea atiende dicha necesidad

  - Entonces elimina el uso de lo ya mencionado
- Para finess de depuración, en lugar de usar `or die.....` recomiendo leas [la doc. al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples) para usar *mysqli_error* si es que sigues de manera procedimental y como dice la documentación: *Devuelve una cadena que describe el último error*
- Considera usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php), es riesgoso que de forma directa permitas el paso de valores dinámicos en tu query
- Considero que trabajes la constitución y ejecución de tus queries en un estilo orientado a objetos (*nuevamente revisa la doc. para que tengas mayor contexto*)

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "SELECT * FROM alumnos01") Esta linea esta mal, esa funcion es para seleccionar la base de datos.
para hacer consultas tenes que usar mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM alumnos01")